# IE 11 css-vars-ponyfill only support :root variable, but not support inline varible

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-variables

inline variable not working in IE 11, even :root variable working with the help of 'css-vars-ponyfill' but inline vaiable still not working in IE 11

```css
:root {
    --bg-color: black;
  }
  
  .main{display:inline-block;
  background:var(--bg-color);width:200px;height:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/css-vars-ponyfill@2"></script>
<div style="--bg-color:red" class="main">

</div>
```

Comment: maybe because IE 11 doesn't support it... if you want to use css variables and have to support IE11 don't use them inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 does not support custom variables.

And its not easy to polyfill it, especially the inline-styles because there is no way to read the original applied value of the style-attribute with javascript - believe me, I've tried everything.

There is a polyfill for ie11 which almost completely supports custom variables.
https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties/

But you have to add inline-styles like that:

```html
<div style="--bg-color:red" ie-style="--bg-color:red">
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS custom property [(var function) does not support IE browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).

You could try to add the [css-vars-ponyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill) polyfill to use it in IE browser, code sample as below:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/css-vars-ponyfill@2/dist/css-vars-ponyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-beautify@1/js/lib/beautify-css.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    cssVars({ 
        // Treat all browsers as legacy
        onlyLegacy: false, 
    });

</script>
<style >
    :root {
        --bg-color: green;
    }
    .main {
        display: inline-block;
        background: var(--bg-color);
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
<div style="--bg-color:red" class="main">
    aa
</div>
```

The result as below:

[image]

Might be you have found that, when using this Polyfill, the Polyfill doesn't scan for inline CSS variables, it seems like this is related to the polyfill, you could check [this issue](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill/issues/51).

For the universal elements we could use the root declaration, for the special element, we could directly use the inline style and `background-color:red` style.